# Where to put the line "serverSocket.accept();" in a multithreaded java program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a program where the server and client can send and receive messages to/from each other at the same time (the same way two people with phones can text each other)

There are three files (the main function file, the server file, the client file) I want to only focus on server and main file for now.

The problem with the server file is that there are two separate threads where each thread has its own separate "run" function so I am wondering where I should put the "socket.accept()" line in order to make both of them work (perhaps before, globally somehow?)

The command line arguments to run the server are

```
java DirectMessengerCombined -l 3000
```

if "-l" is not present, then it will run as a client

The flow of the Server file I think would go something like this (psuedo-code comments) (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
//Server listens for connections 
//then accepts the connection from client
//Recieving msesages:
        //function recieves messages, create and run a functon that recieves messages
        //read from the socket until the other side closes
        //display the recieved message


//Sending: Standard input begins
        //create and run a functon that sends messages
        //write using standard input as long as the user doesn't close it, in a loop


//user close standard input to end the program
```

According to this flow, would it be possible to accept a connection outside the first run method from the thread? Perhaps in the constructor?

Server Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
public class DirectMessengerServer
{

    private String[] serverArgs; 
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;

    public DirectMessengerServer(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        // should serverSocket.accept() go here???



        // set the instance variable
        this.serverArgs = args;
        int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(serverArgs[1]);
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
        socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
    }

      public String[] ServerRun(String[] args) 
      {
        serverArgs = args;
        serverArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
        return serverArgs;
      }


        // should serverSocket.accept() go here???

    Thread ServerRecieve = new Thread();


//If i put serverSocket.accept() in both the run methods, won't that cause an "Address already in use error"? 

//run method of ServerRecieve
public void run(String args[])
{   
    System.out.println("Server recieve thread is now running");
    try
    {


        while(keepRunning)
        {
            //Reading the message from the client


            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client: "+ MessageFromClient);


        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            socket.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Thread ServerSend = new Thread ();

//Run method of ServerSend
public void run()
{   
    while(keepRunning)
    {
        System.out.println("Server sending thread is now running");
        try
        {         

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            //creating message to send from standard input
            String newmessage = "";
            try 
            {
                // input the message from standard input
                BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String line = "";

                line= input.readLine(); 
                    newmessage += line + " ";

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            }
            String sendMessage = newmessage;
            bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+sendMessage);
        }


        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}


}
```

Code of main function file:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectMessengerCombined
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        DirectMessengerClient Client1 = new DirectMessengerClient();
    //  Thread t1 = new Thread(Client1);
        DirectMessengerServer Server1 = new DirectMessengerServer(args);
        //DirectMessengerServer Server1 = new DirectMessengerServer(args[1], null, 0);
          for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {
                if(!args[0].equals("-l"))
                {
                    Client1.ClientRun(args);
                }
                switch (args[0].charAt(0))
                {
                    case '-':
                    if(args[0].equals("-l"))
                    {   
                        Server1.ServerRun(args);
                    }

                }
           i=args.length + 20;
          } 
    }

}
```

My question is: where is the right place to accept the connections in the code so that both run methods will be able to work as if they both were connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you will put it inside a loop in its own thread, and you will start a new thread per accepted connection.

Comment: I see. Where does the ThreadName.start(); go for the outer and inner threads?

Comment: would it be something like `Thread ListeningLoop = new Thread(); 
public void run(String args[])
{  try
    {
   while(keepRunning){
           int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(serverArgs[1]);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
            socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            Thread RecievingLoop = new Thread();
            void run()
            {
            //code to loop reading/recieivng messages
            }`

Comment: Don't ask me to comment on code in comments. You can see for yourself that it's completely illegible. Post it in your question, or another question, where it can be formatted and then read.